# vscode defaults directory to random file every time

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every-time I run code on vscode, the directory becomes /anaconda3/pkgs/anaconda-navigator-1.9.7-py37_0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/static/images

It is frustrating to cd and change the dir every-time and I cannot seem to find a solution for it. Changing the default directory did not work.

Any solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Visual Studio Code keep changing the working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52560881/why-does-visual-studio-code-keep-changing-the-working-directory)

Comment: "code ." does not work